# Inflation Rates from CPI with R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have to create the inflation rate for 20 years(1990-2010). I have now a cvi file with the cpi rates from each month of this 20 years. How can I create now easily the inflation rate in R?

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

````
infl <- cpi[13:n]/cpi[1:(n-12)]
 n <- length(cpi)```

i got this help from my teacher, how can I use this code?

[My File][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYaBN.png
````

Comment: can you provide an example table, e.g. in the form of `df=data.frame(col1=c(...), col2=c(...), ...)`

Comment: Can you post code for whatever you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to `blscrapeR` package which does that already.

Here's also its vignettes which tells you how to use it:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blscrapeR/vignettes/Inflation_and_Prices.html